# Windows 8.1 store apps xaml get download size from server

Tags: xaml, download, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm trying to get download file size before downloading the file...the both ways i know are after starting the download it self in either download operation class or HttpProgress class...but both return the size when starting download.

Comment: Do you have control over the server or is it someone else's server? If it's someone else's server, you likely don't have the ability. You can however, start the download, get the metadata, then stop the download (in case you want to show them the size before getting the whole thing). If it's your server, you can add a query for the size of the file.

Comment: not my server...the other way works but has some junk code!